# how can instagram comment box be focused on using python selenuim or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, bots, instagram

Im trying to make an Instagram bot with python selenuim that comment on posts using Selenium but when trying to click on the comment textarea it doesn't.

I tried with click and focus methods using pure javascript and nothing worked,i also tried every possible method in Selenium library to click on the text area and nothing worked(sendkeys ,click, driverwait then click...etc).

the driver can find the item but it doesn't really click or appear to be focused(cursor flashing).

python selenuim methods that i tried:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"the xpath").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"the xpath").send_keys("comment")
```

note: the problem is not related to driver cant finding the object
I either use driver wait or this method:

```py
while True:
         try:                           
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"the xpath").click()#
            break
         except:
            pass
```

javascript methods that i tried:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('_ablz _aaoc')[0].click();
```

or

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('_ablz _aaoc')[0].focus();
```

when changing the value or innerHTML of the textarea this happens ([text shows up but im not able to press the post button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qv4W.png))
is there any solutions for inserting text into the textarea using selenium library in python or using pure javascript?

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: i did ,check it out.

Comment: _**text based relevant HTML**_: Is what we are expecting.

Comment: I didn't get it, is it the instagram-page HTML code or what?